# Optimize a multi-variable equation in python

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I have an equation of the form:

z = a*x + b*y + c

where x, y, z are variables and a, b, c are constants.

I would like to find the optimum values of a, b and c. What would be the best way to do this in python? `optimize.curve_fit` only works with two variables, not three.

Comment: Are the variables reals? Because in that case, depending of the sings of `a` and `b`, `x` and `y` will always be positive infinite or negative infinite...

Comment: What defines "optimum" for this application?

Comment: Yes, this is a regression problem. 'x', 'y' and 'z' are known data, so I'm trying to minimise the difference between known 'z' and 'ax+by+c'

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing regression? If so, `optimize.curve_fit` works for more than two variables, you just need to pass your variables as a list:

```
def line(x, a, b, c):
    return a * x[0] + b * x[1] + c

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(0., 100., 100)
y = np.random.uniform(0., 200., 100)
z = 3. * x + 2. * y + np.random.normal(0., 10., 100)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, [x, y], z)
print(popt)
```

Results:

```
array([ 2.99156418,  2.00992449, -0.2434515 ])
```